# How to divide a list of images in Python, based on their labels

Tags: python

I have a list of images called *randomData* that they have been labeled with 57 classes. So, this list has two dimensions. The first dimension is the images, and the second dimension is the labels of their classes.

*randomData[0]* is the images, and *randomData[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TLle.png)* is the labels. The question is that in Python, how can I save all images in different groups with the same labels? For example, I want to have a dataset of images with label 0, a database of images with label 1, ..., a dataset of images with label 9. 
I am trying to write the following code:

```
[randomData[0] for i in randonData[1][:] if i==0]
```

But, I do not know how I can consider those *randomData[0]'* which are related to label *i*.

I appreciate your helps.

Comment: Post what you have tried _and_ include representative input data (e.g. your `Dataset` list) and expected output.

Comment: [Very similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31443384/how-to-rearrange-the-rows-in-a-list-of-tuples-in-python).

Comment: And, as I commented in that question, I think you're looking for `[item[0] for item in randomData if item[1]==0]`.

Comment: @ TigerhawkT3, ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

images = defaultdict(list)

for image, label in randomData:
    images[label].append(image)

for k,v in images.iteritems():
   print('Label {} has {} images'.format(k, len(v)))
```

Comment: Done. Thank you. How can I access to groups? I want to have those classes individually for further tasks.   Is it possible to save all classes as different lists? The second question is that how can I get  %70 of each classes in one list? I mean, a list with %70 of all images.

Comment: Each key in the dictionary is the group name. To get 70% just calculate the index at 70% the size of the list for the group you are interested in.

Comment: Done Burhan. Thank you. I chose %70 of them. Now, I am wondering how can I turn back these into one list. I want to add the labels after each image resulting in the tuples with size 2. Is it possible let me know what shell I do?

Comment: Would you please the following code. I could not get the result.


`from collections import defaultdict
images = defaultdict(list)
for image, label in randomData:    images[label].append(image)

a=[]
for k,v in images.iteritems():
   print('Label {} has {} images'.format(k, len(v)))
   tag=[[k] * len(v)]
   tag=tuple(tag)
   tag=np.asanyarray(tag, dtype=np.int64)
   img=zip(images[k],tag)
   a=a.append(img)`

Comment: Update:  For python 3+ images.iteritems() should be images.items()